# Calling a property setter when changing a (nested) property inside the property object

Tags: c#, .net, properties

insane title . . I know . . but bear with me . .

consider the following case:

```
a.ClassProperty.ValueProperty = 4;
```

where:

```
class A
{
    [...]
    public PropertyClass ClassProperty
    {
        get { return new PropertyClass(m_someInformation); }
        set { ComplexMultistepSetInformation(m_someInformation); }
    }
    [...]
}
```

and:

```
class PropertyClass
{
    [...]
    public int ValueProperty { get; set; }
    [...]
}
```

My problem: when executing the first given statement the code will return a PropertyClass object and change the 'ValueProperty' in it, but the information itself for 'a' will remain the same.
What I would like to have is for the setter of 'ClassProperty' being called, after changing the information of the PropertyClass object retrieved via the 'ClassProperty' getter. Meaning, a way to make the first line accomplish the following:

```
PropertyClass tmp = a.ClassProperty;
tmp.ValueProperty = 4;
a.ClassProperty = tmp;
```

Is there any way to change the getters and setters around to accomplish it.

(Additional information: having a PropertyClass object in class A would not help. In the real use case PropertyClass is a wrapper around native code, simplifying access to variables and providing several extension methods, while information for a native object gets 'written' by the setter of property 'ClassProperty')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to change the getters and setters around to accomplish it.

No, not really. The code:

```
a.ClassProperty.ValueProperty = 4;
```

is simply translated into:

```
var tmp = a.ClassProperty;
tmp.ValueProperty = 4;
```

It's *never* going to try to call the `a.ClassProperty` setter.

You might want to change to something like:

```
a.ModifyClassProperty(x => x.ValueProperty = 4);
```

Where `ModifyClassProperty` would effectively do:

- Fetch information
- Applied user-supplied delegate to it
- Perform any steps to apply the changes to the underlying data

For example, you could achieve it with your current code:

```
void ModifyClassProperty(Action<PropertyClass> action)
{
    var tmp = ClassProperty;
    action(tmp);
    ClassProperty = tmp;
}
```